# Get the last row of dataframebased on flag pandas

Tags: pandas

below is a sample df

```
id  val    flag
1    1.2     0
1    1.5     0
```

I want the row where val is minimum and flag is 0,

if i run

```
df.loc[d['val'].idxmin()]
```

i will get row for value 1.2

```
id  val    flag
1    1.2     0
```

in the next step i change flag for value 1.2 to 1.

Now my df looks like

```
id  val    flag
1    1.2     1
1    1.5     0
```

Now i want to find the row with minimum val and also flag = 0, i shud get row with val 1.5, but this code  `df.loc[d['val'].idxmin()]` wont work, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[(df['val'] == df['val'].min()) & (df['flag'] == 0), 'flag'] = 1  
print (df)
   id  val  flag
0   1  1.2     1
1   1  1.5     0
```

Detail:

```
print ((df['val'] == df['val'].min()) & (df['flag'] == 0))
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```